# Order complex object via LINQ

Tags: linq, sorting

I have a complex object:

```
+ Client
     + Products
           + Types
               | TypeId
               | ManagerCode
               | TypeName
                ....
```

A single client will be associated with a collection of products they have bought, and each product will have a collection of types associated with it.

I need to sort the 'Types' on two properties - ManagerCode and TypeName.

eg: `client.Products.ForEach(o => o.Types.OrderBy(o1 => o1.BaseType.ManagerCode));`

Well, when I do this, the list doesn't actually order once returned to the front end. It maintains the original sort order. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderBy` doesn't replace the original collection; it returns a newly-sorted collection.

Assuming `Types` is a list, you need

```
client.Products.ForEach(o =>
    o.Types = o.Types.OrderBy(o1 => o1.BaseType.ManagerCode).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to use the `Sort` method.

```
client.Products.ForEach(o => o.Types.Sort(
    (x, y) => string.Compare(x.BaseType.ManagerCode, y.BaseType.ManagerCode));
```

Comment: I was looking for this - it doesn't mix LINQ and anti-LINQ and probably sorts in-place or something nice like that - but I couldn't find it.